# get value from nested array json angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to get the value from nested array. Some how I was not able to get the value.

Here is my JSON

```
                {
        "VersionNum": "",
        "studyLevel": [{
                "countryName": "StudyLevel",
                "FS": "15-JAN-2020",
                "LS": "10-Jan-2020",
                "FI": "08-DEC-2019",
                "LI": "10-FEB-2019",
                "getData": [{
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "4",
                        "Username": "Vimal",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "5",
                        "Username": "Jack",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "6",
                        "Username": "James",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "countryName": "Country 1",
                "FS": "15-JAN-2020",
                "LS": "10-Jan-2020",
                "FI": "08-DEC-2019",
                "LI": "10-FEB-2019",
                "getData": [{
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "4",
                        "Username": "Paul",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "4",
                        "Username": "Smith",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "countryId": 0,
                        "userId": "4",
                        "Username": "Trumble",
                        "FI": "12-JAN-2020",
                        "LI": "21-Feb-2020",
                        "experience": 5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to access Username from getData Here is my ts code

```
const getUserData = this.dataService.getuserList().subscribe((data:any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.reponsearray = data;   
  this.responseuserName = data.getData[0].Username;   
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of responseuserName ">
           <th  [attr.colspan]="keycount" class="User-names">{{item.userName}}</th>
      </ng-container>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Surely you need to query via `studyLevel`?

Comment: do you want to display all the username? bcs i am seeing in your html you are iterating a loop for displaying a user name

Comment: @YashRami Yes correct

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this. here as you can see we have an array of object the `studyLevel` and inside that we have another array of the object `getData` so we are using the two `*ngFor` loop one inside another

**TS**

```
const getUserData = this.dataService.getuserList().subscribe((data:any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.responseuserName = data.studyLevel;   
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of responseuserName ">
     <ng-container *ngFor="let data of intem. getData >
           <th  [attr.colspan]="keycount" class="User-names">
{{data.userName}}</th>
     </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you please help me on the above JSON request

Comment: @Mahadevan i updated my answer let me know if it is not working

Comment: <th colspan="5"></th>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let row of responsearray.studyLevel">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of row.trialDesignElements">
                         <th [attr.colspan]="keycount" class="trial-names">Treatment length ({{col.treatmentLength}}) </th>
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>

Answer (score 0):

`studyLevel` array has desired data:

```
const getUserData = this.dataService.getuserList().subscribe((data:any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.reponsearray = data;   
  this.responseuserName = data.studyLevel[0].getData[0].Username;   
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create a nested `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of response.studyLevel">
  <div *ngFor="let col of row.getData">
    {{col.Username}} {{col.FI}} {{col.LI}}
  </div>
</div>
```

As a suggestion, you could rename `responseuserName` to `responseuserNames`.

[The work stackblitz example can be seen here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2cpvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: after adding this also the data is not populating  this is my html 

                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of responseuserName">
                    <th *ngIf="item" [attr.colspan]="keycount" class="user-names">{{item.username}}</th>
                </ng-container>

Comment: for that you only need to assign  `this.responseuserName = data.studyLevel[0].getData` @Mahadevan

Comment: @Mahadevan is it ok for you?:)

Comment: @StepUp I am getting error :( Cannot read property 'studyLevel' of undefined

Comment: @Mahadevan have you seen stackblitz example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209863/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-stepup).

Comment: @StepUp Yes I saw your stackblitz

Comment: @StepUp I am getting the same error but I am getting value also